# Deriving the Gauss Constraint in Free Maxwell Theory

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, gauss-law, constrained-dynamics

In section 6.2 (page 128) of [David Tong's Lectures on QFT](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html), Gauss' law is derived for the free Maxwell theory. The result of computing the Hamiltonian of the theory is (eq. 6.17),

$$H = \int d^{3} x \frac{1}{2} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E}+\frac{1}{2} \vec{B} \cdot \vec{B}-A_{0}(\nabla \cdot \vec{E}).\tag{6.17}$$

I am comfortable reproducing this computation, but I do not understand what is meant by the claim:

> *"So $A_0$ acts as a Lagrange multiplier which imposes Gauss' law"*.

Earlier in eq. (6.10), it is established that $A_0$ is not an independent physical degree of freedom, and I'm assuming this fact is somehow operative in the Gauss's law statement. It's not clear to me though.

Comment: Going to Hamiltonian formalism, you actually eliminate the $A_0$ component of the field. However, being fixed to some value it has to still obey the equations of motion. The equation of motion, obtained from variation of $A_0$ is : $\partial_i F^{0 i} = 0 \Rightarrow \partial_i E_i = 0$, which is a Gauss law.

Comment: the Gauss law is not derived on p128 from 6.17. the gauss law is a consequence of the equations of motion as it is written earlier in 6.8. so the constraint is a secondary constraint.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Hamiltonian formulation$^1$ (6.17) has 7 independent fields $A_0$, $\vec{A}$ & $\vec{E}$. In particular $A_0$ acts as a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) in the corresponding (Hamiltonian) Lagrangian.
2. In eq. (6.10) Tong apply an EOM to detemine $A_0$. This does not contradict the fact that $A_0$ is an independent field prior to the use of EOMs.

--

$^1$ Tong is here discussing the situation prior to any gauge-fixing. Note that in the Hamiltonian formulation (6.17) the momentum $E^0$ for $A_0$ has been eliminated by a [primary constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_constraint) $E^0\approx 0$.